# Disable keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: settings, azure-devops

How can I disable keyboard shortcuts in [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) (previously Visual Studio Online)?

They conflict with some Polish diacritical marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting to disable this feature. You can submit a feature request on [the developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/).